# ToIsoString is not a function when I get my date object from v-datetimepicker

Tags: date, vuetify.js, datetimepicker, toisostring

When I use Vuetify datetimepicker, I get the following date: "Wed Mar 16 2022 04:20:00 GMT+0100"

I need to convert this to ISO8601. But if I store this date in a variable called "date" and try to convert it like this:

```
date1 = new Date(date).toISOstring();
```

It returns an error that says "(intermediate value).toIsoString is not a function".

What am I doing wrong here? I'm assuming it's not a valid date object, but how can I then convert this mess into a working date object?

Answer (score 1):

This happenes when the toISOString() method is called on a value that is not a date object. To solve the error, make sure to only call the toISOString() method on valid date objects.

```
const d1 = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(d1); // 2022-03-10T09:15:54.224Z
```

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured, do you have an idea on how I can convert that mess from datetimepicker into a valid date object?

Comment: `new Date('Wed Mar 16 2022 04:20:00 GMT+0100')`. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)